# separating data from a txt file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have data in a txt file and need to separate the data. Apologizes but i am really finding this hard (and maybe hard to explain aswell). the below is the top few lines of the txt file (there are 1000 lines). I need all the data between the first * in row 0 and the last * which is in row 700. I dont want to select by row number as the numbers can change but I want a code which will select the data between the *. Secondly the data is NOT separated into columns and it is one big row. I want a second piece of code which can separate the data into columns ie Latter REPORT, Calculation Date, Index Code are columns (I cant separate on space because it splits Calculation and Date into separate columns when they should be one column.) Please can someone help me and thank you!

```
                                                     0
0                                                    *
1    #124 Latter REPORT                      D51D   ...
2    #  1 Calculation Date                  calc_da...
3    #  2 Index Code                        modes2_in...
4    #  3 Index Name                        index_n...
120  #120 5 Years ADPS Growth Rate          5_years...
121  #121 1 Year ADPS Growth Rate           1_year_...
122  #122 Payout Ratio                      payout_...
123  #123 Reserved 26                       reserve...
124  #124 Reserved 27                       reserve...
125                                                  *
```

Comment: I understand that your file is large, but please share with us a minimal, reproducible file. Instead of having the second * in row 700, have it in row 3 for example, and place the next * in 6 or 7, etc. That way we can test our answers and give you verified solutions.

Comment: Just edited the data - does that help?

Comment: Quick answer for the first part: just use row slicing. dat[1:700] should get everything from index 1 to 699 (the stuff between the asterisks)

Comment: @Sam i dont want to use location of the row as the data can change daily ie the * maybe row 700 today but tomorrow can be 718 etc

Comment: @Zack, ok, gotcha. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the dataframe is called `dat`, for the first part to find the asterisks:

```
asterisk_location = dat[0] == '*'

asterisk_location = asterisk_location[asterisk_location]

start, finish = asterisk_location.index

dat = dat.iloc[start+1:finish]
```

This also assumes you want to get the region between the first two asterisks. If there's more, you'll have to adjust a bit.